# html + java script ! need help to understand why am getting (invalid username or password)

Tags: javascript, html

am trying to do a homework in web dev and there is a part i need help with because it should work but i have no idea why its not
the username in the test is doc1 and the password is pass1

```js
function docauth(event)
{
    var DU = "doc1";
    var DP = "pass1";
    if(document.getElementById("docuser") === DU && 
       document.getElementById("docpass") === DP)
    {
        alert("login success!");
    } 
    else 
    {             
        alert("invalid username or password");
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Doctor page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>doctor login</legend>
        <form id="docLOG" onsubmit="docauth(event)">
        <label for="docuser">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="docuser" name="docuser" required><br><br>
        <label for="docpass">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" id="docpass" name="docpass" required><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </fieldset> 
</body>
</html>
```

it should say after entering doc1 and pass1 (login success!)
what i tried is changing the var DU and var DP and even the if statement from document.getElementById to form.element and adding var form = document.getElementById
but nothing worked

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns an Element - which is an Object, not a String

Comment: Yep.  Go to the browser JS console and type `console.log(document.getElementById("docuser"))` and you'll see what you're getting that's making it not work.  That's also web dev troubleshooting 101 -- log it and see what you get.

Comment: See [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Comment: All `<input>` elements implement the [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) interface.  You'll see that this includes a `value` property, which is "A string that represents the current value of the control. If the user enters a value different from the value expected, this may return an empty string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

```
      if(document.getElementById("docuser").value === DU && 
           document.getElementById("docpass").value === DP)
```

The reason it doesn't work is its comparing the element, not the text the whole entire element. But if you put `.value` after the `document.getElementById` it will work because now its comparing what the user put inside the input.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Doctor page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>doctor login</legend>
            <form id="docLOG" onsubmit="docauth(event)">
            <label for="docuser">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="docuser" name="docuser" required><br><br>
            <label for="docpass">Password:</label>
            <input type="text" id="docpass" name="docpass" required><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
        </fieldset> 
      <script>
        function docauth(event)
        {
            var DU = "doc1";
            var DP = "pass1";
            if(document.getElementById("docuser").value === DU && 
               document.getElementById("docpass").value === DP)
            {
                alert("login success!");
            } 
            else 
            {             
                alert("invalid username or password");
            }
        }

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```